# Skip type check in collection equality in xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, collections, xunit, xunit.net

Having a trivial inheritance

```
private class TestBase : IEquatable<TestBase> {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "test1";

    public bool Equals(TestBase other) => this.Name == other.Name;
}

private class Test : TestBase {}
```

I need to compare two collections:

```
var s1 = new TestBase();
var s2 = new Test();
Assert.Equal(s1, s2); // OK, uses IEquatable
Assert.StrictEqual(s1, s2); // OK uses IEquatable
Assert.Equal(new[] { s1 }, new[] { s2 }); // fails
Assert.Equal<IEnumerable<TestBase>>(new[] { s1 }, new[] { s2 }); // fails
Assert.Equal(new TestBase[] { s1 }, new TestBase[] { s2 }); // fails
```

To me, if `Assert.Equal()` for a single instance uses `IEquatable` interface the collection overload should also use the interface and do not compare types. How do I get the wanted behavior?

Comment: If this trail runs dead, I'd suggest asking on the xunit github

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Fluent Assertions for this comparison?

I think of something like

```
x = new[] {s1};
y = new[] {s2};
x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(y, o => o.Excluding(p => p.Type));
```

which compeares that the two collections of objects are equivalent to each other but ignores the type. I haven't tried the Excluding() part with a type yet, but it works for single object attributes, so maybe try to make it work for your example too.

Further information on Fluent Assertions: https://fluentassertions.com/about/